# Could a controller return binary data?

Tags: 8

This is my javascript request:

```
var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
XHR.responseType = 'blob';
XHR.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
    if (XHR.readyState == 4) {
        if (XHR.status == 200) {
            var blob = new Blob([XHR.response], {type: "application/mp3"});
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'Myfile.mp3';
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        } else {
            document.getElementById(regidrs).innerHTML = "Error: " + XHR.responseText;
        }
    }
});

var FD  = new FormData();
FD.append('uuid', uuid);
XHR.open('POST', '/fetch');
XHR.send(FD);
```

This is my module routing:

my_module/my_module.routing.yml

```
my_module.content:
  path: '/fetch'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyController::content'
    _title: 'Hello World'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

And my controller:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\drupal_set_message;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

/**
 * Defines HelloController class.
 */
class MyController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Display the markup.
   *
   * @return array
   *   Return markup array.
   */
  public function content() {
     ...
        $response= file_get_contents(....);
        $file = file_save_data($response, "public://myaudiofile.mp3", FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
     ...
     return [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $response,
    ];
  }

}
```

But file_get_contents returns a mp3 file, and I need to pass this mp3 to the javascript httpresponse in order to donwload it. 
Saving $response to a file, I have checked the file is ok.

How can I do it?

Comment: Once the question gets answers, its sense cannot be changed, nor can more details be added. In both the cases, the given answers would be invalidated. Questions aren't for an extended back and forth between the user who ask the question and the users who answer. It doesn't work as with forums.

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry. I thought It was the right way to show my changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the [`BinaryFileResponse`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21BinaryFileResponse.php/class/BinaryFileResponse/8.6.x) class, you can return the content of a file in the response. The [`FileDownloadController`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21FileDownloadController.php/class/FileDownloadController/8.6.x) class is an example of controller returning the content of a file. It's the controller for /system/files/{scheme}, /system/files/{filepath}, and /system/temporary.
See its [`FileDownloadController::download()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21FileDownloadController.php/function/FileDownloadController%3A%3Adownload/8.6.x) method.

```
public function download(Request $request, $scheme = 'private') {
  $target = $request->query
    ->get('file');

  // Merge remaining path arguments into relative file path.
  $uri = $scheme . '://' . $target;
  if (file_stream_wrapper_valid_scheme($scheme) && file_exists($uri)) {

    // Let other modules provide headers and controls access to the file.
    $headers = $this
      ->moduleHandler()
      ->invokeAll('file_download', [
      $uri,
    ]);
    foreach ($headers as $result) {
      if ($result == -1) {
        throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
      }
    }
    if (count($headers)) {

      // \Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\FinishResponseSubscriber::onRespond()
      // sets response as not cacheable if the Cache-Control header is not
      // already modified. We pass in FALSE for non-private schemes for the
      // $public parameter to make sure we don't change the headers.
      return new BinaryFileResponse($uri, 200, $headers, $scheme !== 'private');
    }
    throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
  }
  throw new NotFoundHttpException();
}
```

The [`ExportForm`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21locale%21src%21Form%21ExportForm.php/class/ExportForm/8.6.x) class is another example of how to return a file, even if it's a form class. What changes is how the response is used, but how the `BinaryFileResponse` class is used is still relevant for a controller.
The relevant code is the following one, in [`ExportForm::submitForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21locale%21src%21Form%21ExportForm.php/function/ExportForm%3A%3AsubmitForm/8.6.x).

```
$response = new BinaryFileResponse($uri);
$response->setContentDisposition('attachment', $filename);
```

Comment: This is the proper way.

Comment: Thanks @kiamlaluno. I have tried to rewrite my code with your suggestions, but without success. I have edited the question in order to show you my changes.

Comment: @briast You just need to return an object of the `BinaryFileResponse` class. Which hooks the first controller invokes is a different matter, since it is the controller for private files.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to do it. I have tried it in several ways without success. Would you mind if you put me an example. Thanks.

Comment: At least I found the way. The problem was in javascript side.Now it works. I would like to put the solution, but I'm not sure if I should add it as a new answer or update my question. Thanks.

Comment: @briast The question cannot be changed. You could add an answer, but since the question is not about JavaScript, but how to return a file from a controller, it would not make much sense.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Maybe I have not explained well. The solution was your answer, that is, I used BinaryFileResponse as you said. I've changed it and It was the right answer. But It doesn't work because javascript has to be changed to in order to work everything. But don't worry.

Comment: The question asked here is _Could a controller return binary data?_ If then there are other issues in the code, that is a different matter. The question as posted has been answered, but answering a question doesn't mean resolving every issue in the code, including the parts that have not been described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are 99% there, just return a redirect to the file:

```
class MyController extends ControllerBase {

  public function content() {
     ...
        $response = file_get_contents(....);
        $file = file_save_data($mp3, "public://myaudiofile.mp3", FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
     ...
    return new RedirectResponse( file_create_url('public://myaudiofile.mp3'));

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but It doesn't work. On javascript event, I get XHR.status error 500. In Drupal log I see the next error: `Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Drupal\Core\Url could not be converted to string en Drupal\Component\Utility\UrlHelper::isExternal() `.

Comment: I just corrected it. can you re-try, please?

Comment: Briast. Can you try this method. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AtoString/8.2.x

Comment: Cesar, I have changed it but now the error is 404.

Comment: 404 would mean that the file is not there. Can you verify whether the file is really saved?

Comment: Yes. I added file_save_data in order to check the file. It exists and if I download it with Filezilla FTP It is a good mp3 file.

Comment: I see... well, it could happen that the file is on the server, but it is not accessible via HTTP, if you paste the URL on the browser, are you still getting a 404, if so, I think could a file system permissions problem

Comment: We are progressing. I changed public to temporary and now the file is downloaded. But the donwloaded file is smaller than the original. I have changed the javascript code to know the length of the file and It is smaller. I don't know where could be the problem.